# How to solve exponential format modular equation have the same base

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm reading the [paper](http://caislab.kaist.ac.kr/lecture/2010/spring/cs548/basic/B02.pdf) of Taher Elgamal whichs talks about his digital signature scheme.

For example a user needs to sign a document $m \in [0, p-1]$ where $p$ is a large prime number. His private key is $x$ and the public key is $y \equiv \alpha ^{x} \pmod{p}$ where $\alpha$ is a primitive element mod $p$.

The signature of the document is a pair $(r, s)$ where $0 \leq r,s \leq q-1$ such that the equation $\alpha ^{m} \equiv y^{r}r^{s}$ is satisfied.

The signing procedure consists of 3 steps :

1. Choose a random number $k \in [0, p-1]$ such that $gcd(k, p-1) = 1$.
2. Compute $r \equiv \alpha ^{k} \pmod{p}$.
3. Rewrite $\alpha ^{m} \equiv y^{r}r^{s} \pmod{p}$ to $\alpha ^{m} \equiv \alpha ^{xr} \alpha ^{ks} \pmod{p}$.

Then the author said we can compute $s$ by using $m \equiv xr + ks \pmod{p-1}$.

Here is my question: Why it's $p-1$ now? I know that the equation has a solution for $s$ if and only if $gcd(k, p-1) = 1$, but how can we get $m \equiv xr + ks \pmod{p-1}$ from $\alpha ^{m} \equiv \alpha ^{xr} \alpha ^{ks} \pmod{p}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha^m\equiv \alpha^n\pmod p $ where  $m>n$ and $(\alpha,p)=1$

So, $\alpha^{m-n}\equiv1\pmod p \implies ord_p\alpha\mid(m-n)$ ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213361/showing-mathrmord-da-mid-mathrmord-ma-if-d-mid-m/213456#213456))

If $\alpha$ is is a primitive element $\pmod p, ord_p\alpha=p-1$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand the $ord_{p}\alpha \mid (m - n)$ thing, what does it mean? The order of $\alpha$ is $m - n$?

Comment: @user6417, $ord_p\alpha$  means Multiplicative Order(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeOrder.html)  $a\mid b$  means $a$ divides $b$

Comment: So in my case, as $p-1 \mid m-xr-ks$, so $m \equiv xr + ks \pmod{p-1}$ ??

Comment: @vesontio, yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you lab @lab bhattacharjee